# Are heterozygotes always fitter than homozygotes? Can inbreeding be beneficial?

Tags: genetics, evolution, population-genetics, molecular-evolution

Inbreeding is mostly not very good because when there is a 'disease' in one allele, the other could/would take over the function. But when you have two of the same genes/alleles, do they, or could they have advantages? Can inbreeding be beneficial?

Answer (score 2):

Certainly it is not necessarily the case that having two of the same allele is a bad thing - if there is a "bad" allele then there is a "good" allele. It can be that the heterozygote is equal, better than, or worse than either [homozygote](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zygosity#Heterozygous). When the heterozygote is fitter than both homozygotes it is called [heterosis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heterosis) and, when this is the case, outbreeding/hybridisation is advantageous.

The process of inbreeding *can* actually improve fitness because it increases the rate at which deleterious mutations (bad mutations) are expressed, and therefore the efficacy of selection. If the population avoids fatal [inbreeding depression](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inbreeding_depression) it can have positive effects. This process of removing deleterious variants by inbreeding is called [genetic purging.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_purging)

Comment: A good example of homozygotes being more fit might be [Polled Cattle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polled_livestock). The allele that makes horns on cattle is actually recessive, so a cow needs two copies to have horns. A cow with horns is better able to defend itself in the wild. It also allows them to outcompete other cattle for food on the farm, and can be a safety issue for the farmer. By breeding bulls to be homozygous for the dominant no-horns allele, you can easily remove horns from a herd and avoid costly, and potentially harmful, surgical horn removal.

Answer (score 0):

The phrasing in quite unclear and I would not be able to comment on it.

In short: yes, hybridization can cause offspring to have either particularly low or particularly high fitness. [Hybrid depression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inbreeding_depression) refers to cases where hybrids have low fitness while [heterosis or hybrid vigour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heterosis) refers to cases where hybrids have a higher fitness than any of the two parent lines.